# Using JSON and SQL for a mobile app

Tags: jquery, sql, json, mobile, cordova

I'm trying to make a mobile application using jQuery Mobile and Phonegap. But first of all I'd like to say that I'm not a professional programmer; I'm only a student trying to understand de basics of a mobile application. I do have some experience in HTML and PHP. 
So I'm trying to learn myself some of the basics of a mobile application; I tried it before but due to a lack off time I did not have the time to investigate the problem I was experiencing back then.

The thing I'm trying to realize is quite simple:
I have a SQL database with: names (1), where they work(2) and a description(3). All of them have an unique ID - So 4 tables.
First thing I'd like to pull from the database is their names according from where they work.

I tried to follow several tutorials, guides and read trough some other stuff. This is what I came up with. This is a PHP-file placed on the server.

```
  <?

include 'includes/db.php';

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM work");

$array = Array();


if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{
    for($i=0; $i < count($sql); $i++){
         $rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
        $array[name] = $rec['name'];                   
    }

    echo json_encode($array);
}

?>
```

When I open this PHP-file I do get a result back from the database, formatted in JSON. But I'm only getting one name in return while there are more names in that database.

Next I'd go and place the jQuery code in the jQuery-Mobile app like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $.getJSON('names.php', function(data){
                $("#namesDiv").html(data);

            });

        });
</script>
```

Ofcourse this is not returning anything; this I'm still trying to figure out how to display all the names as a list in the HTML file. 
But after this I want to be able to tap on a name from that list and get the description from that person on a next page. I know in PHP you can get the ID from the URL (page.php?id=1) and then pass it on in your query to get the correct data; but how can this be done when JSON is handeling everything?

I hope someone can help me out; I know I'm asking a lot and that my knowledge is maybe insufficient but I would really appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery.getJSON( url, [data], [success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] )

url: A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.

data: A map or string that is sent to the server with the request.

success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR)A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds.
```

you can send `id` like

```
$.getJSON("names.php",{id:id)},function(json){

//do what ever you want with json

});
```

and in your names.php do

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

**query part**

```
$temp = array();
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM work"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

if(empty($temp))
   $temp=array($row['name ']);
else    
   array_push($temp,$row['name ']);    
}
echo (json_encode($temp));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your query; but I can't seem to get it working. I just get an empty [] on the PHP-page. I'm trying to understand what is happening on every line of the code and if I understand correctly "$row" contains an array with all the results from the $sql-query and then being looped by the While. the IF is making an array from the row name and else is pushing the results onto the end of array? (I admit, I googled)  I don't understand what the 'empty' bit is doing in the if-statement though? Is there something I'm looking over or forgetting something so it's not working?

Comment: after the while loop place `print_r($temp)` that will print the contents of `$temp` i dont know why you are getting empty results, if your query is executing properly you should get the results

Comment: When I use `print_r($temp)` I still get no results. I did found when I change `$result` in the while-loop to `$sql` I do get results. So bypassing `$results=mysql_query($sql)`; I have no idea why it is doing that though. But can this bypassing do any harm? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Lucas very sorry for the confusion i copy pasted the code so made this error, i have edited the answer ehat you are doing is the right way...

Answer (score 0):

You do this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM work");
...
count($sql)
```

Read the manual page for [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query), you'll see that it doesn't return an array with the rows, it returns a *resource*. In the loop, you have to test the return value of [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) instead.